# Seating Algorithm with Constraints

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-algorithm

I am trying to make a program in which, over 5 days, a new seating arrangement is produced every day.  There is a constraint that must be followed:

- People are seated in groups of 4, and cannot be in the same group with another person more than once over the course of the 5 days.  There are roughly 30-35 people in total.

I have done a bit of research already, and it seems that this is a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), but I was wondering if this kind of problem has a more specific name, or specific algorithm to be used with it.

In addition, is it possible to determine if this constraint is able to be met with a given sample size?  I am new to the realm of graph theory, and do not know which algorithms are viable in this situation.

Comment: Yes, it's the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below is a good starting point for the Social Golpher Problem. It contains solutions for the simpler cases (including some with 4-tables) and gives pointers to some more advanced papers: http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have looked into the Social Golfer problem, along with a few of its efficient algorithms because I need to implement one of them into a Java program.  Do you know if this has already been done in Java before?

Comment: There is a nice writeup at https://www.metalevel.at/mst.pdf which describes exact solutions for some special cases from design theory and a heuristic search approach as well as a constraint satisfaction approach

Comment: @mcdowella Thanks, this one seems even better than the one I linked.